# How could I import jQuery from npm package using ES6 only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm

I installed jQuery with npm -install jquery and it created a node_modules folder in my project with jquery in it. But when I try to import it using ES6 import it gives me an error.

I don't want to use Webpack or require() and have to compile it... anything else just plain vanilla ES6.

I'm always gettting this error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module
>   './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js' does not provide an export
>   named '$'

or

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module
>   './node_modules/jquery/src/jquery.js' does not provide an export named
>   '$'

**Project structure**

```
.
├── index.html
├── app.js
├── node_modules/
│   ├── jquery/
│   │   ├── dist/
│   │   │   ├── jquery.js
│   │   │   ├── jquery.min.js
│   │   ├── src/
│   │   │   ├── jquery.js
└── package.json
```

**app.js**

```
import { $ } from './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'; // <-- does not work
import { $ } from './node_modules/jquery/src/jquery.js'; // <-- does not work
window.$ = $;

$('body').css('background-color', 'red')
```

Comment: But wait. jQuery is a client-side library, are you trying to import it in Node? And then use it in Node with `$('body').css()`? What am I missing?

Comment: No, I just wanted to use npm as a package manager and include it in browser.

Comment: So what's wrong with `<script src="jquery.js">` ?

Comment: Sorry, node.js was the wrong tag.

Comment: IIRC jQuery provides only a default export, not a named `$`. So maybe try `import $ from './node_modules/jquery/...` (or any name you like instead of $)

Comment: @JeremyThille I wanted to use the new ES6 syntax of import/export.

Comment: @TobiasK. The requested module './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js' does not provide an export named 'default'

Comment: Use `type="module"` in script `<script type="module" src="app.js"></script>` but then if you are not running this on server you need to remove CORS.

Comment: @NenadVracar I already have type="module"

Comment: And try `$` instead of `{ $ }`.

Comment: @NenadVracar I tried $ and it says there is not default export for jQuery

Comment: Just `import  './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'` works for me.

Comment: Thanks Nenad, that finally worked!

Comment: Since you use modules and ES6, what’s the point of jQuery ⁉️

Comment: @NenadVracar Can you please put your comment as an answer. Because it worked for me and if you had put it as an answer, I would not have to read all the comments. Doing so will help many.

Answer (score 2):

Try `npm install jquery` and then `import $ from "jquery"`.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "jquery". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: Oh, you aren't using webpack. Then you can't import/export stuff. Just include jquery script into the head of html file. After that you can just use $ in your code, without importing anything.

Comment: You can use imports/exports, using Webpack with Babel. Otherwise stick to plain <script src="something.js"> thing.

Comment: I can use import/export in any modern browser without webpack. It's ES6 syntax.

Comment: @Liga By using import `jquery`, you mean to refer to `node_modules/jquery`. Try using import `import $ from './node_modules/jquery`

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, this functionality is only beginning to be supported by browsers. 
Full implementation is provided in many transpilers such as TypeScript and Babel, and bundlers such as Webpack.

ES6 modules have been fully supported in Chrome since version 65 but it still throws errors if we try and use the import/export keywords to import or export modules in JavaScript files.

So what do you have to do to make ES6 modules work without Webpack/Browserify/Babel is to add next script tag in your index.html file:

```
<script type="module" src="ES6-Node.js"></script>
```

Comment: All modern browsers support ES6 import/export as far as I know